# Is there anyway to put complete message after startActivity()?

Tags: java, android

(Oh, first of all, I'm sorry for my bad English)

Hello~!

I just started to learn android programming.

I tested sending an intent object with "text/plain" to messenger app and checked it worked properly.

After sent the intent object completely, I could see a toast-like message box like below(orange one).

[image]

**I want to add some confirm message like 'message sent' to that toast-like message.**. What should I do?

Thank you.

**Updated**

Here's my code.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.message_edit);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plan");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());

    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

}

and this is the build.gradle setup of module.

```
compileSdkVersion 29

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.actionsendexam"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Once again, thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Hi could you edit your question by adding the code for the  tickbox toast message so that we can give you a solution.

Comment: @Kidus, I'm sorry for the late update. I added the source code and manifest. Thank you for the interest. :D

Comment: I don't see anything in your code to display any kind of toast after sending the intent, are you sure it is the correct Activity?

Comment: @Kidus, That toast-like message, with the checkmark, is not what I added. When startActivity(intent); has been running, it just shows up. This is why I tell you this toast-like message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Toast message`

You can use like :

`Toast.makeText(this, "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

If you put this code after what you want to do, you can see the toast message with the text.

Also if you want to check the detail, you can check  [Android official document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts)

If you have any problems, please leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to add the string message to that toast-like box? I don't want to show additional message box.

Comment: What kind of code did you put for that tick mark? Did you use the toast message or anything else?

Comment: No, nothing. I just used the startActivity() method. The code is...        

EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.message_edit);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plan");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());

if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
}

This is all. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

send a text like this in kotlin

```
Val intent = Intent(this, AnotherActivity::Class.java)
intent.putExtra("Key",value)
startActivity(intent)
```

Now get Like this In another activity

```
val String = intent.getStringExtra("Key").toString()
```

Then For Toast

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I wrote above, I just want to add some message to that box but not to show another toast message box. I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Okay I understand what you are saying now it is happening because you use the action method  (Intent. ACTION_SEND), that why it sowing, I have never used that so I also don't know about that much but will give you an answer as soon as possible

Comment: You're right. My English was not clear and it made you confused. I'm so sorry and thank you for your understanding. Oh, I updated the question and added my code! :D